# foldLeft, foldRight difference on List Accumulator using Scala

Tags: scala

This

```
Seq(2,5,-7,4).foldLeft(0)( (acc, a) =>
    if (a > 0) acc + a else acc )
```

gives 11

This

```
Seq(2,5,-7,4).foldRight(0)( (acc, a) =>
    if (a > 0) acc + a else acc )
```

gives 7

I am surprised why, as a straight aggregation has no such issue. I.e. the results are the same. For the above 11 seems correct to me.

Reason - some Scala implementation?

Comment: You have an error in your `foldRight` `(acc, a)` it should be `(a, acc)` because the accumulator comes from the right.

Comment: Thats an answer

Comment: In all honesty I find that strange and checked with a few persons as well. It is an answer imho. Cheers

Comment: Why do you find it strange? That the reasoning if you are folding from the right the accumulation comes from the right. If you are folding from the left, the accumulator comes from the left. Check the function signature: https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez   I would not have thought that 'functionally' that would be an issue.  But I stand corrected and will inform others. I look at scala from spark perspective. May be that's it. Anyway.

Comment: **Spark** due its distributed nature, doesn't have `foldLeft` or `foldRiht` but just `fold`, because there is no concept of order on a **RDD**, as such neither value is the accumulator, there are just two values that may be merged together.

Comment: We're getting off track now, so I will leave it, but I thank you for the learnsome moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a and acc need to be reversed for foldRight. Checked with a few people, no one guessed or knew that. Hence the answer.

```
Seq(2,5,-7,4).foldRight(0)( (a, acc) =>
    if (a > 0) acc + a else acc )
```

Thanks to @LMMS.